# Namespace System.Math gets overshadowed after adding a reference with Math.<xyz> namespace

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, csproj, .net-5

I've got an issue when importing a package/library that introduces namespace `Math.Native.Gmp` (it's called "Math.Gmp.Native" on NuGet).

Before import, this code works perfectly fine:

```
using System;

namespace Sample
{
    public int Foo()
    {
        return Math.Min(1, 2);
    }
}
```

After adding this reference, however, `Math` is no longer recognized as a `System.Math`, but is hidden by the newly added namespace - `Math.` expects only `Math.Native` as the correct extension of the path.

Trying to use `Math.Min` ends up with compiler error:

> [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'Min' does not exist in the namespace 'Math' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I found out that original `Math` is still accessible via `System.Math`, so in the example above, after adding this prefix (`return System.Math.Min(1, 2);`) everything works as intended. It is some walkaround

My question is - how to avoid that overshadowing of `Math`? Can I use some `using` commands at the beginning of the file to avoid it?. Can I make some alias for `Math.Native.Gmp` namespace so that it won't be conflicting with `System.Math`?

Comment: `using System.Math;` maybe?

Comment: you could try `using MathNativeGmp = Math.Native.Gmp;`

Comment: @AKX Math is a type, so only `using static System.Math;` compiles. It is another walkaround - `Math.<xyz>` can be accessed just by writing  `<xyz>`

Comment: @WombleNumber1 it creates additional alias, but leaves `Math.<xyz>` untouched - CS0234 error upon using `Math.Min`

Comment: @Quilir strange, I would expect the alias to override the default namespace if it is not otherwise 'used' in the file - as per the following example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/XDPnqH

Comment: @WombleNumber1 `System` is still accessible in this example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/rtTy8m

Comment: @Quilir I have updated that fiddle further to show more clarification

Comment: Actually @Quilir I have updated that again now with reference to the library that you are talking about, and I think the best solution is the answer that Markus Safar gives below. Realistically it is going to be best to do the alias for 'System.Math' rather than the other way around due to the unfortunate naming of the base namespace for the Math.Gmp.Native - https://dotnetfiddle.net/XDPnqH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation of the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) you can use something like

```
using myMath = System.Math;
```

to define an alias for a namespace.

Comment: I think this is the best (possibly the only) solution given that the base namespace for the Math.Gmp.Native library is 'Math' - an unfortunate conflict.

Answer (score 1):

There IS a way to resolve this conflict by moving `Math.Gmp.Native` namespace away. That can be done by setting an alias to that library. In `.csproj` file of our project set ("Gmp" is just a selected name by me):

```
<PackageReference Include="Math.Gmp.Native.NET">
    <Aliases>Gmp</Aliases>
</PackageReference>
```

In that way `Math.<xyz>` no longer means things from that library, but - as intended - from `System.Math`.

In files where you want to use the imported library, you have to include:

```
extern alias Gmp;
using Gmp::Math.Gmp.Native;
```

It won't create conflicts either!

**HUGE WARNING:** This solution has a massive drawback. When you want to use this project in your second project, the second project will have exactly the same issue. Although `Math.Gmp.Native.NET` is a just nested reference, it causes the same overshadowing of the `Math` namespace.

So, in every project using `Math.Gmp.Native.NET` anywhere in a tree of references, `Math` is overshadowed by the library's one. If you want to use `Math` there as the default `System.Math`, you got to include in its `.csproj` same code shown above.

It gets messy and hard to follow why `Math` doesn't work without that magic reference in the `.csproj` file in the project not even using (directly) anything from this library. That is why I haven't chosen this answer as an accepted one

Answer (score 0):

To build up on alrady given answer:

whenever you have this conflict, `System.Math` was there first. So to make things working again use in every file `using` statement:

```
using Math = System.Math;
```

If you want to use the other namespace easily, you can rely here on @MarkusSafar answer and use some custom alias:

```
using OtherMath = /*other math namespace*/;
```

or just use fully qualified names.

Comment: Adding that alias causes a conflict:  "[CS0576] Namespace '<global namespace>' contains a definition conflicting with alias 'Math'". That is - old `Math` definition from `Math.Gmp.Native` is still there